# <img> tag not respecting max-age, and unnecessarily reloading images

Tags: html, browser-cache, cache-control

I have a cgi program written in C that outputs gif images, writing them to stdout, and preceded by the cache control lines,

```
fprintf(stdout,"Cache-Control: max-age=99999\n");
fprintf(stdout,"Content-Length: %d\n",nbytes);
fprintf(stdout,"Content-Type: image/gif\n\n");
```

And the CGI is invoked from an HTML page with a tag of the form

```
<img src="http://example.com/cgi-bin/gifprogram.cgi?query_string">
```

where query_string is the usual form *variable=value&etc* describing the gif to be generated by the program. It works okay (at least to the extent I've tested it), but images are re-downloaded whenever I reload the HTML page, despite the max-age emitted by the program.

Static images, i.e., where *src="http://example.com/image.gif"* points to a file, seem to work okay, and they're just reloaded from the client browser cache. So I'm guessing (totally guessing) the problem's related to the fact that the tag's dynamically running a program on the server, and that fact somehow overrides the max-age. Is that right? Or what? And how, if there's a way, can I get the browser to re-use its cached images when the page is reloaded?

Note: I'm testing with Linux (Slackware 14.2) firefox 45.2.0, but have seen the same behavior with Mozilla and Konqueror. Haven't had an opportunity to try Windows.

**Edit** Thanks @JefréN for solution, and here's a demo of now-working program,

http://www.forkosh.com/gifscroll.xq?message=%5CLARGE%5Cbf%7B%5Chspace%7B8%7D%5Cfbox%7B%5Cfbox%7B%7B%5C%20Thanks,%5C%20JefreN%5C%20%7D%7D%7D%5Chspace%7B8%7D%7D&nscroll=4&nflicker=6&fg=4&bg=0&margin=52&njitter=4&vjitter=.50&password=forkosh&nzoom=6&zoomn=-10%20&%20bg2=0&nchk=0&btype=3&bmargin=24&bwidth=48&bshape=1&bsfrac=.50&bfrac=.43&cband=3,5,6,7,13,5,11,2&fgb1=-1&fgb2=-99

Comment: @prashanthpadala You forgot to capitalize "Firefox":)  And as long as we're being pedantic, I've left your "is the usual form", but my original "is of the usual form" is more correct. Whenever in doubt, try to fill in any missing words. In this case, that would be "query_string is **formatted in** the usual form". Query_string is **not** a "usual form", it's a string of characters. And that string is formatted **in** "the usual form". I simply shortened that to the vernacular "**of** the usual form". But removing that "of" is simply wrong. If you want to be pedantic, okay. But try to be right.

Comment: This advice isn't guaranteed, but I think your problem is because of the dynamic url. Haven't we heard of adding a query parameter to a resource url to force browsers to always load the resource?

Comment: Thanks, @JefréN. I'm by no means an html expert, and had to look up http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/D/dynamic_URL.html Now, having done so, that sounds like a **terrific** guess. So how to get around that??? I'm thinking, change the url to _src="http://example.com/gifprogram?query_string"_ and make a symlink _gifprogram-->cgi-bin/gifprogram.cgi_. You think that would work? Thanks again.

Comment: @JefréN. Okay, that simple fix doesn't work. What happens is that _src="example.com/gifprogram"_ links to cgi-bin/gifprogram.cgi okay, but the now-static url just downloads the program binary file itself rather than executing the program and downloading its stdout output. But that result strongly suggests to me that your diagnosis is right. Question is: how to get around it??? I want to have my cake and eat it, too. That is, treat the url as static with respect to browser caching, but get the server to execute the program. Any way to do that???

Comment: What server are you using? Can you add rules to your configuration?

Comment: Thanks, you solved it, @JefréN. After some googling, I added the two lines, AddHandler cgi-script .xq and Options +ExecCGI to the .htaccess in my http://example.com/ "root" directory, and cp'ed cgi-bin/gifprogram.cgi to /gifprogram.xq And that now works. (But trying to just symlink gifprogram.xq-->cgi-bin/gifprogram.cgi threw a 500 error. I'm guessing that's because the symlink has 777 permissions which I couldn't chmod to the required 755.) If you like, post as an "answer", and I'll upvote and accept it. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for the offer; it's appreciated. However, the solution you found wasn't even what I was thinking of. (I was going to try a redirection type scheme.) Because *you* found the answer and it wasn't what I was anticipating, I don't think it is ... ethical to post the answer that I wasn't aware of. :) Good job on solving your problem, though. :)

Comment: @JefréN. Okay, thanks. So instead of accept/upvote, I've edited the question adding a small example of the gifprogram.cgi, displaying a "Thank You" message.

Comment: @JefréN.: _"Haven't we heard of adding a query parameter to a resource url to force browsers to always load the resource?"_ - that is called a cache buster, and uses a _different_ parameter value each time (f.e. the current timestamp), so as to make them _different_ URLs to the browser, that therefor simply can't be taken from cache (because each individual, different URL has never been requested by the client before.) But that does not mean that all "dynamic URLs" prevented caching per se.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe Couldn't see headers from browser (tools->page_info->media on firefox doesn't seem to show them). So tried wget --save-headers and that seems to work. But I'm not seeing anything relevant, just... **HTTP/1.1 200 OK / Date: Mon, 28 Nov 2016 23:15:16 GMT / Server: Apache / Cache-Control: max-age=9999 / Content-Length: 266223 / Keep-Alive: timeout=2, max=100 / Connection: Keep-Alive / Content-Type: image/gif** Anything you see relevant there? Or anything additional I can have the program emit that would make the desired difference? Thanks. (P.S. Why'd you remove your comment?)