# Will errno == ENOENT be a sufficient check to check if file exists in C?

Tags: c, file, errno

Using PellesC on Windows 8.1.

I know this topic has been addressed many times with many solutions. I have read solutions stating the usage of `CreateFile`, `PathFileExists`, `GetFileAttributes`, `_access` which I somewhat understand.

I have also read an important point about race conditions in the answer to the questions [Quickest way to check whether or not file exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44741326/quickest-way-to-check-whether-or-not-file-exists)
and [What's the best way to check if a file exists in C? (cross platform)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230062/whats-the-best-way-to-check-if-a-file-exists-in-c-cross-platform).

So if I open a file using `fopen()` in C and when it fails (for any reason) and passes `NULL` back; then can I further check for `errno == ENOENT` and be content with it and report correctly that the file does not exists.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int file_exists(char filename[]) {
    int err = 0; //copy of errno at specific instance
    int r = 0;   //1 for exists and 0 for not exists
    FILE *f = NULL;

    //validate
    if (filename == NULL) {
        puts("Error: bad filename.");
        return 0;
    }

    printf("Checking if file %s exists...\n", filename);

    //check
    errno = 0;
    f = fopen(filename, "r");
    err = errno;
    if (f == NULL) {
        switch (errno) {
          case ENOENT:
            r = 0;
            break;
          default:
            r = 1;
        }
        printf("errno = %d\n%s\n", err, strerror(err));
    } else {
        fclose(f);
        r = 1;
    }

    if (r == 0) {
        puts("It does not.");
    } else {
        puts("It does.");
    }

    return r;
}
```

Comment: If you want to report back the cause of the error to the user, then using `errno` is indeed what you want. If you want to know if a file *exists*, then the absence of an `ENOENT` does not guarantee that (you could have gotten another error like `EPERM` eg., or the file could have been created as part of the `fopen` call, or ...). Can you describe in a bit more detail what you're trying to achieve ?

Comment: I shall post code. wait a minute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`fopen` needs to do lots of stuff and checking before the file is opened. `ENOENT` *implies* that the file does not exist, but *file not existing* does not imply `ENOENT`.

It is possible for a file to not exist and you to get another error, such as `EACCES` for not being able to read the parent directory for example.

---

On the other hand, `ENOENT` from `fopen` does not mean that some other process couldn't have created the file even before `fopen` returns or before you're inspecting the `errno` and so on; this is the reason why C11 added the `x` flag for opening a file for *writing* in exclusive mode - failing if the file already exists.

---

To sum it up: if you get `ENOENT`, the file did not exist when you tried opening it. If you get some other error, then each other error code would belong to one of 3 these classes - that it is certain that either

- the file existed, or
- it *cannot have existed*
- or it might have existed at the time

at the time of opening. It is up to you and your required logic how you'd handle these other errors. A simple way would be to refuse to continue processing, reporting the error to the user.